# Moving to Wales from Canada - I am a British citizen by descent. My husband and child are Canadian citizens

Tags: uk-visa, family

I am a dual citizen with the dream of moving back to the UK- with my husband and child who is under 2 years old. My husband works remotely and I am currently not working as I have been at home with our baby but would plan to when I arrive in UK. I am British by descent only and know my child does not receive automatic citizenship as result. We have savings to demonstrate we are financially in a position to support ourselves. I wonder if anyone has moved under similar circumstances and can offer some guidance on the process? With thanks!

Comment: Can your husband's employer handle international remote work, including tax and employment law issues?